# Dojo 1.6 - set Dijit.Select selected by label

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm working with Dojo 1.6, and unfortunately I cannot upgrade to any of the later versions. I have a Dijit.form.Select widget that is being populated dynamically through AJAX.

I am trying to set the selected option based on the **label** not the **value**

Is there anyway to set the selected option this way? Something similar to:

```
dijit.byId("mySelectId").attr("value", "matchingValue");
```

Answer (score 0):

Query the widgets' [store](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojo/store.html#dojo-store-api) for item with the desired label. Then set the value of the select with the result from the store.

Comment: Can you please provide an example on how to do this for a dojo widget based on its ID? I have never done any work with Dojo Store(s).

Comment: There are some nice [tutorials](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/) on dojos website. [This one](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/selects/) and [that one](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/selects_using_stores/) are covering the select widgets.